# Row_number with create virtual field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes

How can using  @row_number option or similar together the command "Create virtual field". It works very well with "Create new field", but doens't work with "Create virtual field".

Comment: You can't, *Virtual Fields* are purely expression based and row related, and are recalculated with each update. They have no concept of the table as a whole, necessary to keep track of the row count.

Comment: Do you have any other ways to create a virtual field that contains the number of each row inserted in the table? Always up-to-date during row inclusion and delete edits?

Comment: Instead of a virtual field, consider using a regular field with a default value. In layer properties > fields, use `@row_number` for the default value, and check the option to auto-update.

Comment: I tried but in the option - Layer properties - Source fields there is no default value.

So I tried the option - Layer properties - attributes form - Defauts - apply default value on update, but the @row_number command does not seem to exist on this form.

Answer (score 1):

As @ThingumaBob suggested, virtual fields do not have to be relied upon for assessing a table context.

For example in your case is no assurance that the order will remain the same after an update.

As a possible **workaround**, however, you could resort to use the `$id` function in a virtual field:

[image]

Comment: I tried to use $ ID, but my problem is that I do include and exclude rows in the table and the $ ID command always appends the ID, if I delete rows, the sequence is always a rising counter.