# How to use the field calculator to generate an autoID

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, autoincrement, autofields

I am trying to get the Field Calculator on QGIS to create an autoID and I am using this expression

```
'5EL_' ||@row_number
```

It works in the preview, but when executed the field is blank.

How do I fix this?

I have also tried

```
'5EL_' ||$id
```

but for some reason I am getting `-x` for the id part e.g. `5EL_-32` with the next feature drawn being `5EL_-33`.

Comment: Please remember to always add the exact software in use in each Question.

Comment: Have you explored $rownum?

Comment: if its working in preview but not executed, then most probably the reason is a different data field type. try again '5EL_' ||@row_number on a text field.

Comment: What file format is it? Is that virtual layer?

Comment: I have tried $rownum and there is no such thing (red squiggly underlined). It is a virtual field and I do have it on text - I have tried several different types and still not working

Comment: you can look into this:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328177/row-number-with-create-virtual-field-in-qgis

Comment: I have tried this too and its still outputting NULL values

Answer (score 4):

You are on the right track. Use `'5EL_' ||$id`. This expression produces a string. Therefore, the field you create have to be `Text`, otherwise, you get `NULL`.

[image]

In edit mode, QGIS uses negative id numbers. After saving, they are converted to suitable sequential positive numbers.

[image]

Comment: I have tried making new features and saving and this is not the case unfortunately

Comment: For some reason it is now working 9not sure why wasn't before) - thank you